# Check whether a table should have 3 records for last the 3 months continuously within a range of 3 month?

Tags: sql, oracle

In my table I have YMonth column which have value in YMONTH in YYYYMM format(like 201510).  Currently I am doing this,

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable WHERE XXX AND YMONTH 
in(TO_CHAR(add_months(SYSDATE,0),'YYYYMM'),
TO_CHAR(add_months(SYSDATE,-1),'YYYYMM'),
TO_CHAR(add_months(SYSDATE,-2),'YYYYMM'))
```

If count=3 then OK. Otherwise, I will execute,

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable WHERE XXX AND YMONTH 
in(TO_CHAR(add_months(SYSDATE,-1),'YYYYMM'),
TO_CHAR(add_months(SYSDATE,-2),'YYYYMM'),
TO_CHAR(add_months(SYSDATE,-3),'YYYYMM'))
```

If count=3 then OK. Otherwise, I will execute,

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable WHERE XXX AND YMONTH 
in(TO_CHAR(add_months(SYSDATE,-2),'YYYYMM'),
TO_CHAR(add_months(SYSDATE,-3),'YYYYMM'),
TO_CHAR(add_months(SYSDATE,-4),'YYYYMM'))
```

This is working great. But I wanna make it simple and only want execute just one sql.

Comment: Is PL/SQL ok for you?

Comment: Yes I am looking for Oracle SQL?

Comment: SQL and PL/SQL are different. IF you are OK using PL/SQL, then you could achieve it using an `IF-ELSE` construct in an anonymous PL/SQL block.

Comment: @LalitKumarB anything that works but lets make it simple. But doing in IF ELSE means 3 queries and I dont wanna this.

Comment: Perhaps if you explain your exact requirement then there could be a better solution. Reading your topic title, it seems it could be done in single SQL. Can you post some data and desired output.

Comment: @LalitKumarB, I just need it should be continuous for 3 months. The above SQL is fine for me if executed 3 times.

Comment: You could use **LAG()** analytic function to check that in single SQL. Seems like you are looking for [**GAPS AND ISLANDS**](http://lalitkumarb.com/category/gaps-and-islands/)

Comment: Is (XXX, YMONTH) unique?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a hierarchical query to find consecutive months:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/96abab/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable ( YMONTH ) AS
          SELECT '201511' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT '201510' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT '201509' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT '201508' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT '201507' FROM DUAL
```

**Query 1**:

This query will return one row for each distinct consecutive set of entries within a 3-month period. In the table above there are three 3-month periods (Jul-Sep, Aug-Oct and Sep-Nov) so the result set returns these three rows.

```
SELECT YMONTH AS FROM_YMONTH,
       CONNECT_BY_ROOT( YMONTH ) AS TO_YMONTH
FROM   MyTable
WHERE  LEVEL = 3
START WITH TO_DATE( YMONTH, 'YYYYMM' ) BETWEEN TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ) - INTERVAL '2' MONTH AND TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' )
CONNECT BY PRIOR TO_DATE( YMONTH, 'YYYYMM' ) - INTERVAL '1' MONTH = TO_DATE( YMONTH, 'YYYYMM' )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/96abab/2/0)**:

```
| FROM_YMONTH | TO_YMONTH |
|-------------|-----------|
|      201509 |    201511 |
|      201508 |    201510 |
|      201507 |    201509 |
```

**Query 2**:

If you do just want a numeric value for the maximum number of (up to 3) consecutive months within the period then you can use this (although it won't tell you which set of months had that period):

```
SELECT MAX( LEVEL ) AS Max_Consecutive_Months
FROM   MyTable
START WITH TO_DATE( YMONTH, 'YYYYMM' ) BETWEEN TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ) - INTERVAL '2' MONTH AND TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' )
CONNECT BY PRIOR TO_DATE( YMONTH, 'YYYYMM' ) - INTERVAL '1' MONTH = TO_DATE( YMONTH, 'YYYYMM' )
AND        LEVEL <= 3
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/96abab/2/1)**:

```
| MAX_CONSECUTIVE_MONTHS |
|------------------------|
|                      3 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it in single query. Combine those condition in one query then sort YMonth *DESC* and limit by *ROWNUM*

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT XXX,YMONTH 
    FROM MyTable 
    WHERE XXX 
    AND YMONTH IN(
        TO_CHAR(add_months(SYSDATE,0),'YYYYMM'),
        TO_CHAR(add_months(SYSDATE,-1),'YYYYMM'),
        TO_CHAR(add_months(SYSDATE,-2),'YYYYMM'),
        TO_CHAR(add_months(SYSDATE,-3),'YYYYMM'),
        TO_CHAR(add_months(SYSDATE,-4),'YYYYMM')
    )
    ORDER BY YMONTH DESC
) WHERE ROWNUM <= 3
```

Please try the query above, and let see if it works.

Comment: It should be 3 and should be continous

Comment: @user960567 If the table has records : `102015,092015,072015,062015` so the query return nothing?

Comment: Let make it simple. I need count should be 3 if I pass Oct, Sept, Aug. Else I need count should be 3 if I pass Sept, Aug, July. Else I need count should be 3 if I pass Aug, July, June.

Answer (score 0):

Order your table by YMONTH and add a rownum column:

```
-- test data
with mytable as
 (select '201501' as ymonth
    from dual
  union
  select '201503' as ymonth
    from dual
  union
  select '201504' as ymonth
    from dual
  union
  select '201505' as ymonth
    from dual
  union
  select '201507' as ymonth
    from dual
  union
  select '201508' as ymonth
    from dual
  union
  select '201510' as ymonth
    from dual
  union
  select '201511' as ymonth from dual),

ordered_data as
 (select ymonth, row_number() over(order by ymonth desc) as r
    from mytable)

select * from ordered_data;
```

result:

```
ymonth  r
201511  1
201510  2
201508  3
201507  4
201505  5
201504  6
201503  7
201501  8
```

With this result you can group by `add_months(ymonth,r)`. Rows with the same value belong together, i.e.

```
ymonth  r add_months(ymonth,r)
201511  1 201512
201510  2 201512
201508  3 201511
201507  4 201511
201505  5 201510 -
201504  6 201510 - first group of tree
201503  7 201510 -
201501  8 201509
```

The following sql delivers the last month of your three month range, adapt it for your needs:

```
-- test data
with mytable as
 (select '201501' as ymonth
    from dual
  union
  select '201503' as ymonth
    from dual
  union
  select '201504' as ymonth
    from dual
  union
  select '201505' as ymonth
    from dual
  union
  select '201507' as ymonth
    from dual
  union
  select '201508' as ymonth
    from dual
  union
  select '201510' as ymonth
    from dual
  union
  select '201511' as ymonth from dual),

ordered_data as
 (select ymonth, row_number() over(order by ymonth desc) as r
    from mytable)

select max(d.ymonth)
  from ordered_data d
 where add_months(to_date(d.ymonth || '01', 'YYYYMMDD'), r) =
       (select max(add_months(to_date(dd.ymonth || '01', 'YYYYMMDD'), r))
          from ordered_data dd
         group by add_months(to_date(dd.ymonth || '01', 'YYYYMMDD'), r)
        having count(*) >= 3);
```

[sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/9921)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're expecting the output of your single query to be, but perhaps you're after something like:

```
with mytable as (select 1 xxx, 201511 ymonth from dual union all
                 select 1 xxx, 201510 ymonth from dual union all
                 select 1 xxx, 201509 ymonth from dual union all
                 select 1 xxx, 201508 ymonth from dual union all
                 select 2 xxx, 201510 ymonth from dual union all
                 select 2 xxx, 201509 ymonth from dual union all
                 select 2 xxx, 201508 ymonth from dual union all
                 select 3 xxx, 201511 ymonth from dual union all
                 select 3 xxx, 201509 ymonth from dual union all
                 select 3 xxx, 201508 ymonth from dual union all
                 select 3 xxx, 201507 ymonth from dual)
-- end of mimicking the mytable table with data in it
select xxx,
       ymonth,
       case when count(case when to_date(ymonth||'01', 'yyyymmdd') between add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), -2) and add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), 0) then 1 end) over (partition by xxx) = 3 then 'last_3_months'
            when count(case when to_date(ymonth||'01', 'yyyymmdd') between add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), -3) and add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), -1) then 1 end) over (partition by xxx) = 3 then 'last_3_months_but_1'
            when count(case when to_date(ymonth||'01', 'yyyymmdd') between add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), -4) and add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), -2) then 1 end) over (partition by xxx) = 3 then 'last_3_months_but_2'
       end month_range
from   mytable
where  to_date(ymonth||'01', 'yyyymmdd') between add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), -4) and add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), 0);            


       XXX     YMONTH MONTH_RANGE                     
---------- ---------- --------------------------------
         1     201511 last_3_months                   
         1     201510 last_3_months                   
         1     201509 last_3_months                   
         1     201508 last_3_months                   
         2     201510 last_3_months_but_1             
         2     201509 last_3_months_but_1             
         2     201508 last_3_months_but_1             
         3     201511 last_3_months_but_2             
         3     201509 last_3_months_but_2             
         3     201508 last_3_months_but_2             
         3     201507 last_3_months_but_2
```